# Check if multi-variable function is differential

Tags: derivatives, metric-spaces, partial-derivative

The function is:$$f(x,y,z) = \begin{cases}
x^2y^2z^2\sin(\frac{1}{xyz}),  & \text{if $xyz\ne0$} \\
0, & \text{if $xyz = 0$}
\end{cases}$$

I need to say where is it differentiable, find the differential, and find at which points it is differentiable continuously.

At points where $xyz \ne 0 $, $f$ is a composition of two differentiable functions, thus it is differentiable.

Also I found that at each other point the partial derivatives equal zero,
since for example: $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h,y,z)-f(0,y,z)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2y^2z^2\sin(\frac{1}{hyz})-0}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} hy^2z^2\sin(\frac{1}{hyz})=0$$

Now I know that the function is differentiable at those points if $$f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{a}) - D(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}) = o(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})$$

where $D$ is the gradient which equals $(0,0,0)$ and $\mathbf{a}$ is a point where $xyz=0$, which means I need to show that: $$x^2y^2z^2\sin(\frac{1}{xyz}) = o(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})$$
However that doesn't work for me. Does it mean that it is not differentiable at those points?

Moreover, by looking at the partial derivatives I came to the conclusion that $f$ is continuously differentiable at every point at which $xyz=0$, since the partial derivative, for example, contains the expression: $yz\cos(\frac{1}{xyz})$

Am I correct here?

Comment: When you say "However that doesn't work for me.", do you mean that you have not been able to prove it true?  This doesn't mean anything; just because you can't prove something does not mean that it's false.  Or instead, do you mean that you have been able to to prove it false?  In this case, yes, that means that it is not differentiable there, since this is a definition of differentiability.

Comment: By the way, your use of "differential" is not standard in English: instead of "differential", we say "differentiable", and instead of "differential in continuity", we say "continuously differentiable".  Only when you say "find the differential", that could be correct, although I wonder if you might mean "find the gradient" instead.  Nothing to worry about!  But I thought that you might like to know.  (I'll probably edit the question to use standard terminology.)

Comment: I wasn't able to prove it true. But I am also not sure how to show that it is false.

Comment: So I'm in a need of assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial derivative doesn't just *contain* $yz\cos(1/xyz)$; it *is* $2xy^2z^2\sin(1/xyz) - yz\cos(1/xyz)$, where $xyz\ne0$.  If the limit of this, as $xyz\to0$, is $0$ (the partial derivative where $xyz=0$), then $f$ is continuously differentiable where $xyz=0$; otherwise not.  Actually, you need to do separately the points where one variable is $0$ (the coordinate planes), those where two variables are $0$ (the coordinate axes), and the point where all three are $0$ (the origin).  By symmetry between the variables, it's continuously differentiable on the coordinate planes if the limit is $0$ as $x\to0$ with $y,z\ne0$ and as $y\to0$ with $x,z\ne0$; it's continuously differentiable on the coordinate axes if the limit is $0$ as $x,y\to0$ with $z\ne0$ and as $y,z\to0$ with $x\ne0$; and it's continously differentiable at the origin if the limit is $0$ as $x,y,z\to0$.

Wherever $f$ is continuously differentiable, it's differentiable, without having to check anything about $o(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})$.  For the places that you still need to check, by symmetry, you can assume that $x=0$ but $y,z\ne0$ at $\mathbf{a}$ (for $\mathbf{a}$ on a coordinate plane), $x,y=0$ but $z\ne0$ at $\mathbf{a}$ (for $\mathbf{a}$ on a coordinate axis), or $x,y,z=0$ at $\mathbf{a}$ (for $\mathbf{a}$ the origin).  (But you won't actually have to all of these after the previous result.)  So for example, if $x=0$ but $y,z\ne0$ at $\mathbf{a}$, you are looking at $\mathbf{a} = (0,y_1,z_1)$, so $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,z)$ with $x\to0$, $y\to y_1$, and $z\to z_1$, so $\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\rVert = \sqrt{x^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2}$, so you want to show that $$x^2y^2z^2\sin(1/xyz)/\sqrt{x^2+(y-y_1)^2+(z-z_1)^2} \to 0$$ as $(x,y,z)\to(0,y_1,z_1)$.  Do you see how to do this?

Comment: By the way, I've distinguished $x$ (one of the three coordinates) from $\mathbf{x} = (x,y,z)$ (the entire point), also in my edit to the question.  And one last English detail from that edit: we say that things happen "at" a point rather than "in" a point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So is it correct that at the origin and at each point where $xyz$ and two coordinates go to 0, the function is continuously differentiable?

Comment: And where only one coordinate goes to 0, then the function isn't

Comment: That's what I got! :-)

Comment: So you just need to check, if only one coordinate goes to zero, is it differentiable?  Only this question involves the limit with the square root.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is differentiable at those points because you can bound the limit and use the sandwich theorem.

Comment: Thank you again for your help! :)

Comment: Yes, I agree.  (I always find these sorts of questions a little tricky, so hopefully somebody else will speak up if these answers are wrong.  But since you got the same results as I did, that's a good sign!)